# Get return variable from serialport

Tags: javascript, at-command, node-serialport, angular1.6

With this function i got empty return

Help me to write correct function

```
 $scope.result= sendread("AT+GMR") //get value datas.toString() or Not OK
     console.log($scope.result) // undefined 

    function sendread(input){
    port.write(input+'\r\n')
    port.drain(() => {
     port.once('data',(datas) =>{
         if (datas.toString().match(/"OK"/g)) {
            return 'Not OK'
           }
           return datas.toString() //652a09gg.Q2406B 1489876 060706 17:19  OK
     })
     })
     }
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

full code as request in comment

```
<script src="http://localhost/angular.min.js.js"></script>
    <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="srpcrtl">
    result : {{result}}
    <br>
    com {{com}}
    <script>
      'use strict';
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('srpcrtl', function($scope) {
        var portName = "COM1"
        const serialPort = require('serialport');
        const port = new serialPort(portName, {
          baudRate: 115200,
          dataBits: 8,
          parity: 'none',
          //parser: serialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n')
        })
        $scope.com = port.path
        console.log('port is now open');
        port.on('open', function() {

          $scope.result = sendread("AT+GMR") //get value datas.toString() or Not OK
          console.log($scope.result)

          function sendread(input) {
            port.write(input + '\r\n')
            port.drain(() => {
              port.once('data', (datas) => {
                if (datas.toString().match(/"OK"/g)) {
                  return 'Not OK'
                }
                console.log(datas.toString())
                return datas.toString()
              })
            })
          }
        })
      })
    </script>
    </html>
```

additional details
$scope.result on html print empty ,$scope.result  on console print undefined ,console.log(datas.toString()) print correct result "652a09gg.Q2406B 1489876 060706 17:19 "

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: @UsmanRana no errors in console

Comment: is this your full code ?

Comment: just edited with full code

Answer (score 1):

i can't explain but working now

thanks

```
port.on('open', function() {

  sendread("AT+GMR", function(res) {
    $scope.result = res
    $scope.$apply();
  })

})

function sendread(input, cb) {
  port.write(input + '\r\n')
  port.drain(() => {
    port.once('data', (data) => {
      if (data.toString('utf8')!=="OK") {
        cb("not OK");
      }
      cb(data.toString('utf8'));
    })
  })
}
```